# Mysql query logic and the loop that returns same variable over and over

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi so I have made a query that when I try and loop out the results it loops out the same variable over and over. It is not an indefinite loop and because of the data it's too tricky to tell if it has looped the correct amount of times. What I'm trying to do is: select all distinct customer_uid's from the customers table where the start_cycle_uid (from the start_cycle table) has the same customer_home id and the same start_date that is passed in. So I'll get one of each customer that belongs to that customer_home on that start date. What I get is a list of the same customer_uid. Is my logic wrong?

```
$homeQuery=$DB->prepare("select distinct customer_uid from customers
                            where start_cycle_uid =
                                (select uid from start_cycles
                                    where customer_home_uid=".$DB->quote_smart($_REQUEST['homeid'])."
                                    and start=".$DB->quote_smart($_REQUEST['start']).")");

$homeResult=$DB->query($homeQuery);
$homeRow=$DB->fetchArray($homeResult);  
if ($DB->numRows($homeResult) > 0) {
    for ($x=0; $x<=$DB->numRows($homeResult); $x++){
        echo $homeRow['customer_uid']."<br />";
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Current code looks like this:

```
$homeQuery=$DB->prepare("select distinct customer_uid from customers
                                where start_cycle_uid =
                                    (select uid from start_cycles
                                        where customer_home_uid=".$DB->quote_smart($_REQUEST['homeid'])."
                                        and start=".$DB->quote_smart($_REQUEST['start']).")");

    $homeResult=$DB->query($homeQuery);
    while($row = $DB->fetchArray($homeResult))
    {
       echo $row['customer_uid']."<br />";
    }
```

This is now stuck in an indefinite loop.

Comment: Follow what your code does step by step: 1) query, 2) **get one result row** 3) if there are more than 0 result rows... 4) loop as many times as there are result rows... 5) **output the one row you fetched in 2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is redundant. The common practice is to iterate through row *while they are present*  - you don't need to retrieve count of rows then. It will be like

```
while($row = $DB->fetchArray($homeResult))
{
   //now you have $row as actual fethed DB row
}
```

-this will work since assignment will return same as `$DB->fetchArray($homeResult)` - i.e. `false` when there's no more rows - which will cause loop end.

Comment: this now loops indefinitely

Comment: What do you mean 'indefinite'? May be 'infinite'? But that's strange then. Which driver are you using (however, no matter what driver it is, this should work)

Comment: indefinite, without limit, forever, infinite. have a look at the code update above, see if there is anything amiss

Comment: fixed it, problem was my end

Answer (score 0):

To get next rows you have to move `$homeRow = $DB->fetchArray($homeResult);` inside the loop. Now it gets only first row because you're calling it once.

It's also good idea to put `$DB->numRows($homeResult)` into variable to avoid counting on each loop run.